# Xamarin debug crash on OPPO R7g

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Every time I push any apps to my OPPO R7g running Android 5.1 (API 22) it crashes before it even gets the chance to load. I have tried running the exact same app on Samsung Pocket Neo running 4.1.2 (API 16) and it tuns perfectly fine. I have tested with both my app and the Xamarin test app, neither work on the R7g and both work on the Neo. I am setting the android version correctly when pushing the app to the phone

Application Output: http://pastebin.com/NgrjgqSd

Any clue what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in debug it may be that the mono runtimes didn't install property for debug purposes. You can right click on your Android project and under options go to Android Build and uncheck "Use shared mono runtime" and give that a try. You may also then need to go to the Advanced tab and select the ABI's you want to support for debug purposes.

You may also simply want to try to go to your OPPO and under settings/apps uninstall anything that says "mono runtime" or "Xamarin.Android" and try again.

Comment: Debug still fails (http://pastebin.com/P9NMgX7P) however the app will run when run directly from the phone. Thanks